Can't remove directory despite 775 and belonging to group
I can't delete folders without being a sudo user.
From what I have understood, a user should be able to delete a folder if it's set to 775 and the user belongs to the group who owns the folder.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
The folder testdir (which is empty) is like this:
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Oct 29 15:55 testdir

testdir is in /var/www, the www folder has 755:
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 30 13:21 www

The user is like this:
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),33(www-data)

I run rm -rf testdir and get:
rm: cannot remove 'testdir': Permission denied


A user should  be able to delete an empty directory if the parent directory has perms 077x and the user is in the group that owns the parent. You're not making a change on the deleted directory, you're changing the parent. You need to chmod 0775 /var/www for this to work.
